# jQuery pick next div in a list to show

Tags: jquery, list, random, timer

I have some jQuery going here:

```
$('#ticker1').hide();
$('#ticker2').hide();
$('#ticker3').hide();

$("#ticker").oneTime(2000,function(i) { /* Do the first pull out once */

    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3); /* Pick random div to show */
    $('div#ticker div:eq(' + randomNum + ')').show();

    $("#ticker").animate({right: "0"}, {duration: 800 });

});

$("#ticker").oneTime(20000,function(i) { /* Do the first retract once */

    $("#ticker").animate({right: "-450"}, {duration: 800});

    $("#ticker").oneTime(1000,function(i) { 

        $('#ticker1').hide();

    });

});

$("#ticker").everyTime(21500,function(i) { /* Everytime timer gets to certain point */

    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    $('div#ticker div:eq(' + randomNum + ')').show();

    $("#ticker").animate({right: "0"}, {duration: 800}); /* Pull out right away */

    $("#ticker").oneTime(20000,function(i) { /* Retract once */

        $("#ticker").animate({right: "-450"}, {duration: 800});

    });

    $("#ticker").oneTime(21000,function(i) { /* Hide all divs once */

        $('#ticker1').hide();
        $('#ticker2').hide();
        $('#ticker3').hide();

    });

});
```

I am trying to get it to show a random div the first time it pulls out, which has been accomplished in the first part of the code. But after that right now I have it grabbing a random div (out of 3 divs) everytime after that too. I need to change this part of the code so it looks at the list of 3 divs and goes to the next one down every time.

So if the first time the div that pulled out was 2 then every time after that would go in this order: div 3, div 1, div 2, div 3, div 1 etc.

Here is a demo of what is going on right now: treethink.treethink.net/backup

Thanks,
Wade

Comment: Why are you using oneTime without employing `this`? Use setTimeout. Also, look up jQuery animation callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of generating a new random number every time, generate it first then increment it with a mod 3, that way you will get the next divs in order.

for example, if your random number generated 2, the next one would be 3%3 = 0, then 1%3 = 1 then 2%3 = 2 and so on.

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

$("#ticker").everyTime(21500,function(i) { /* Everytime timer gets to certain point */

randomNum = (randomNum+1)%3;

$('div#ticker div:eq(' + (randomNum) + ')').show();


$("#ticker").animate({right: "0"}, {duration: 800}); /* Pull out right away */


$("#ticker").oneTime(20000,function(i) { /* Retract once */

    $("#ticker").animate({right: "-450"}, {duration: 800});

});

$("#ticker").oneTime(21000,function(i) { /* Hide all divs once */

    $('#ticker1').hide();
    $('#ticker2').hide();
    $('#ticker3').hide();

});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm just having one issue now actually with this. The first 2 are the same, so the first one will be a random number, next will eb that same number then after it will go one up. I changed $('div#ticker div:eq(' + (randomNum++%3) + ')').show(); to $('div#ticker div:eq(' + (randomNum+1) + ')').show(); and it fixed that but then after that it won't show the next one just stay on the same one.

Comment: if you break it into two lines it may fix your problem, the problem is it's not actually updating the randomNumber with the randomNum+1

Comment: How would I break that up? Sorry, I'm very new to jQuery.

Comment: Still the same problem unfortunately. Here is my code right now: treethink.treethink.net/backup/jquery.js I think it has something to do with my initial oneTime function that does the first one up front?

Comment: i didnt notice  you were showing it the first time in another function, updating the code.  just moved the randomNum increment to the line before the one showing the div.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't realize that, makes total sense. Thanks a lot, take care John!